# Error with spaces in formated json result in link in 'load' function in JQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

I have a problem with JSON and jQuery. I want to send a formatted JSON result in the link in the `.load()` function.

```
<?php
$array = array(
    "test1" => "Some_text_without_space",
    "test2" => "Some text with space"
);
$json = json_encode($array);
?>
<div id="test1"></div>
<div id="test2"></div>
<script>
    function Test(value) {
        var obj = JSON.parse(value);
        console.log(obj);
        $('#test1').html(value);
        $('#test2').load('http://example/some_link_even_one_that_doesnt_return_anything.php?json='+value);
    }
    Test('<?php echo $json; ?>');
</script>
```

When in the JSON result there are no spaces - it is good, but only when there is at least one space there is something wrong and I have no idea why.

I try adding encodeURIComponent(value) but it doesn't change anything, there is still an error.

This is console:

```
{test1: "Some_text_without_space", test2: "Some text with space"}
test1: "Some_text_without_space"
test2: "Some text with space"
__proto__: Object

jquery.min.js:2 Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: text with space"}
    at Function.fa.error (jquery.min.js:2)
    at fa.tokenize (jquery.min.js:2)
    at Function.fa [as find] (jquery.min.js:2)
    at n.fn.init.find (jquery.min.js:2)
    at Object.<anonymous> (jquery.min.js:4)
    at i (jquery.min.js:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.min.js:2)
    at z (jquery.min.js:4)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (jquery.min.js:4)
```

and the site return this:

```
<div id="test1">{"test1":"Some_text_without_space","test2":"Some text with space"}</div>
<div id="test2"></div>
```

Comment: It looks like the issue in JSON . Can you provide JSON response so that we can help a little bit

Comment: Take a look at the javascript function encodeURI

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_encodeuri.asp

Comment: @OussamaEssamadi: _I try adding encodeURIComponent(value) but it doesn't change anything, there is still an error._

Comment: Not sure where you get your example JSON string. It is not valid. Try using something like jsonlint. You want `{"test1":"Some_text_without_space","test2":"Some text with space"}`. Your code works fine if supplied valid JSON.

Answer (score 0):

The example/test JSON does not appear to be valid. I don't think it would be returned by PHP's `json_encode`.

```
$json = json_encode(
    [
        "test1" => "Some_text_without_space",
        "test2" => "Some text with space"
    ]
);

var_dump($json);
//string(66) "{"test1":"Some_text_without_space","test2":"Some text with space"}"
```

Passing that string shown above to JavaScript's `JSON.parse()` works as expected. JSON lint on your example gives:

> Error: Parse error on line 1: {   test1: "Some_text_wi
>   --^ Expecting 'STRING', '}', got 'undefined'

Another option is to simply insert the JavaScript Object instead of a string. You could then skip the parse functions.

Example:

```
<script>
  <?= var json = <?= json_encode($array) ?>;
  Test(json); //having removed the parse call.
</script>
```